# Unix domain socket: A socket operation encountered a dead network

Tags: c#, unix, .net-core, tcp, unix-socket

I'm using Unix Domain Socket for the first time,
I have created the following console application using .NET 5.0 to learn about Unix Domain Sockets.
I found the code here (https://medium.com/codex/unix-domain-sockets-in-net-6-basics-and-real-world-examples-8982898ab293)

My expectation is that similar to TCP/IP socket connection, i will be able to talk between the client and server but using Unix Domain sockets instead.
Following is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string Hostname = "localhost";
        const string UnixSocketPath = "/tmp/foo.sock";

        using var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

        var endpoint = new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(UnixSocketPath);
        socket.Connect(endpoint);

        var requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {Hostname}\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
        socket.Send(requestBytes);

        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
        socket.Receive(receivedBytes, 1024, SocketFlags.None);

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedBytes));
    }
}
```

I get the following error when i try to run my application:

"A socket operation encountered a dead network" at socket.Connect(endpoint) line.
I have the following questions:

1. Is it expected for the above console application to run in a windows system?
2. After reading couple of articles i understand that the "UnixSocketPath" is the file based path which is followed in a Unix machine. What does it refer to in case of a Windows machine? Or is it just a temporary file created in the output directory of the application.

I tried the following to resolve the error "A socket operation encountered a dead network" after reading up a bit on this:

1. Try to run the application in admin mode - does not work, same error
2. Switch to .net core 3.0 (even though i was not facing any compile time errors with .net 5.0)

- does not work, same error.

3. Tried to change the "UnixSocketPath" to a local path (Eg: C:/Test/foo.sock ) - does not work, error : "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. C:/Test/foo.sock"

Excuse me for these noob level questions, the entire socket level programming is new to me and i'm quite confused now .
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/ for information on using unix domain sockets on Windows

Answer (score 0):

From your posted link:

> To run the example on Windows-based systems, I can recommend WSL 2. Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code come with excellent remote integrations so you can run the code directly from the development environment.

WSL is "Windows subsystems for linux", i.e. a linux virtual machine that has some integrations with the windows host.

So you would need to run your program in this WSL environment, and have this configured correctly.  See [Debug .NET Apps in WSL with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022)

However, if you just want your server and client to talk to each other I would consider if this really is the right approach. While unix domain sockets might have some performance advantages, you require both applications to be run on the same computer. I would just use some message based protocol and instead try to minimize the number and size of messages.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out. So that means that Unix domain sockets can run only in Linux systems, correct?                                                              To answer your question, I'm trying to understand about the Unix domain sockets using a simple example. The use case itself is different.

Comment: @Atom99 this is the first time I have heard of Unix domain sockets, but I would assume it is a unix specific thing from the name.